# Typescript how to declare a function that returns a lowest common denominator type?

Tags: typescript2.0, declare

i want declare a function that returns a common type or its extended type

```
interface Common {
  id: number;
}

interface AdditionalInformation extends Common {
  myname: string;
}
```

Surely the function returns an object containing the **id** property

and wishing it could also return the **myname** property

I tried to declare the function like this:

```
export class Lib {

  public static lowestCommonDenominator <T extends Common>(): Common {
    const a: Common = { id: 1 };
    return a;
  }

  public static firstCaseFunction(): Common {
    const ok: Common = this.lowestCommonDenominator();
    return ok;
  }

  public static secondCaseFunction(): AdditionalInformation {
    // Property 'myname' is missing in type 'Common' but required in type 'AdditionalInformation'.ts(2741)
    const ko: AdditionalInformation = this.lowestCommonDenominator();
    return ko;
  }

}
```

But when I assign the function to an extended type, I get the error:

> Property 'myname' is missing in type 'Common' but required in type
>   'AdditionalInformation'.ts(2741)

Is it possible to implement what I want?

Comment: It's quite unclear what do you mean by common denominator but I guess what you're after is [union types](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/discriminated-unions.html)

Comment: i want remove the error from my example

Comment: imagine that you have a function that can return 100 types all derived from Common

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet removes the error

```
export class Lib {
  public static lowestCommonDenominator <T extends Common>(): T {
    const a: Common = { id: 1 };
    return a as T;
  }

  public static firstCaseFunction(): Common {
    const ok: Common = this.lowestCommonDenominator();
    return ok;
  }

  public static secondCaseFunction(): AdditionalInformation {
     const ko: AdditionalInformation = this.lowestCommonDenominator<AdditionalInformation>();
    return ko;
  }
}
```